# Get closest attribute value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div id="admin_chatRoom">
   <div class="msg_box admin-msg-box  1444229594038" style="right: 0px; margin-right: 7px;">
      <div class="msg_head activated" offset="0" c_id="1444229594038"><a id="2" class="closeChat" title="End Chat"><span class="fa fa-ban"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: none;" class="msg_wrap display-hide">
         <div class="msg_body">
            <div class="msg_a temp_msg">hio</div>
            <div class="msg_push"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="msg_footer"> <textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="msg_box admin-msg-box  1444288416317" style="right: 250px; margin-right: 10px;">
      <div class="msg_head activated" offset="0" c_id="1444288416317"><a id="3" class="closeChat" title="End Chat"><span class="fa fa-ban"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="display: block;" class="msg_wrap display-hide">
         <div class="msg_body">
            <div class="msg_a temp_msg">hio</div>
            <div class="msg_push"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="msg_footer"> <textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get value of c_id attribute from `<div class="msg_head activated" offset="0" c_id="1444229594038">` which is closest to current textarea.

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("keypress", ".admin-msg-box textarea", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var msg = $(this).val();
            alert($(this).closest('c_id').val());
        }
    });
});
```

But it shows undefined. Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't use non-standard attributes like `c_id`. If you need custom attributes, use data attributes like `data-c_id`.

Comment: closest just looks through an elements parents and wont actually find the closest element including siblings and sub-childs of parents/ siblings. select the most outer element and use find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `c_id` attribute is not valid - you should use `data-*` attributes so that your page does not contain invalid HTML markup. Secondly, the `.msg_head.activated` element is not a direct parent of the `textarea`, so `closest()` won't work for you here. Finally, the `c_id` selector will look for an element of that type, not one with that attribute.

To do what you require you can use `closest()` from the `textarea` to get the nearest containing `.msg_box`. From there you can find the `.msg_head` which has the attribute you require, and then finally you can use `data()` to read its value. With all that said, try this:

```
<div id="admin_chatRoom">
    <div class="msg_box admin-msg-box  1444229594038" style="right: 0px; margin-right: 7px;">
        <div class="msg_head activated" data-offset="0" data-c_id="1444229594038">
            <a id="2" class="closeChat" title="End Chat">
                <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
            </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="msg_wrap display-hide">
            <div class="msg_body">
                <div class="msg_a temp_msg">hio</div>
                <div class="msg_push"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_footer">
                <textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msg_box admin-msg-box 1444288416317" style="right: 250px; margin-right: 10px;">
        <div class="msg_head activated" data-offset="0" data-c_id="1444288416317">
            <a id="3" class="closeChat" title="End Chat">
                <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
            </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;" class="msg_wrap display-hide">
            <div class="msg_body">
                <div class="msg_a temp_msg">hio</div>
                <div class="msg_push"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="msg_footer">
                <textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on("keypress", ".admin-msg-box textarea", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        alert($(this).closest('.msg_box').find('.msg_head').data('c_id'));
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8y7b3pa/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".admin-msg-box textarea", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        var c_id = (($(this).parents('div.msg_box.admin-msg-box')).find('.msg_head.activated')).attr('c_id');
        alert(c_id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest only select direct parents. the div you are trying to select is a sibling to parent. Also use .attr() method to read attribute value and not .val()

try this instead:

```
alert($(this).closest('.admin-msg-box').find('div[c_id]').attr('c_id'));
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7cxrrg/)